# unable to install ubuntu 13.04 on a system pre-installed with windows8

Tags: installation

I made my USB "liveUSB" using "linux live usb creator" with source as "ubuntu 13.04.iso file" and also I changed my "uefi fimware settings" as it was there in installation guide for ubuntu 13.04.But when i try booting using my usb it's again booting into windows8,I'm unable to understand why? ,here in my case i'm unable to even see ubuntu live image screen rather seeing a blackscreen with underscroll at the top for sometime and then my system's booting into windows8.  My system is "ASUS S56C ultrabook" with intelx86 processor and also pre-installed with windows8.

Comment: Have you seen your boot order? Is it set to boot the usb first?

Answer (score 0):

some boot systens cant support file format older then fat16 and cant read USB 
you need to use any partition software to change fat table from fat32 into lower (older)
second common reason is that many computers do not check USB even when asked to. 
You can try using plob boot manager

Comment: How to change fat table from fat32 into fat16 or anyother version

Comment: This is more likely a case of not correctly installing on Windows 8.  There is a question that answers how to install on UEFI Windows 8 systems, and I have marked this as a duplicate of that (see my comment on the question itself)